# Время загрузки Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, долгая-загрузка

*Android Studio* загружается неприлично долго. Создал пустой проект в Android Studio, сохранил и все закрыл. Открываю Android Studio снова (с этим пустым проектом). Время с момента клика по иконке до `gradle build finished` - 12 минут 25 секунд. На пустом проекте! Как это ускорить?

Comment: какая система установлена?

Comment: Windows 7 профессиональная, Intel core i5-3470S 2.9GHz память 8Gb

Comment: Android Studio работает хорошо только на Linux и OSX, у меня на винде была такая же беда

Answer (score 1):

Распределитель нагрузку на все ядра , с помощью Диспетчера задач , немного ускорит процесс ...